# biblatex: \textcite author formatting vs. bibliography author formatting

Tags: biblatex

For LaTeX citations, I use biblatex/babel. The journal for which I'm writing requires a bibliography with authors formatted as follows:

> Guyton AC, Hall JE.

That is, with no "and" before the last author. I did manage this (see example below), however, in `\textcite`, "and" is also gone now...

Questions

1. Is it possible to remove "and" in the bibliography, but leave it in `\textcite`.
2. Previously, I used `\textcite` together with the authoryear style. Using a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28461/biblatex-tighter-integration-of-textcite-in-the-flow-of-text) also posted on this website, I was able to put multiple sources in one `\textcite`, and `biblatex` would place commas and an "and" at the appropriate places. Is it possible to adapt this solution for numeric citation styles?
3. Is there a way to make all authors (and the commas in between them) bold in the bibliography?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[
  terseinits=true,
  firstinits=true,
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric
]{biblatex}

%Put initials after names...
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}    

%Remove "and" before last name. However, this also removes "and" in a textcite...
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}

%I also removed the commas between last names and initials (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17583/biblatex-remove-commas-between-last-and-first-names-in-bibliography). This is however not needed for a minimum working example.

%Generate a test bibliography
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{database.bib}
@BOOK{Guyton2006,
  title = {Textbook of Medical Physiology},
  publisher = {W.B. Saunders},
  year = {2006},
  author = {Arthur C. Guyton and John E. Hall},
  address = {Philadelphia, Pennsylvania},
  edition = {11th Edition}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{database.bib}

%Some biber compatibility things (from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21711/setting-up-winedt-6-0-and-miktex-to-run-biblatex-and-biber)...
\makeatletter
    \providecommand\bibstyle@faked{}
    \providecommand\bibdata@faked{}
    \AtBeginDocument{%
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\noexpand\bibstyle@faked}%
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\noexpand\bibdata@faked}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
The following sentence contains a textcite example. \textcite{Guyton2006} wrote a comprehensive textbook.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ad question 1: Simply use

```
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}%
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Question 2 can be resolved by upgrading to the latest biblatex release.

Question 1 is resolved in part by new biblatex features, but to ensure use of the `and` string in `\citeauthor` you can incorporate the `\ifcurrentname` test in a redefinition of `\finalnamedelim`.

For question 3 note that the sort name list in the bibliography corresponds to either `author`, `editor` or `translator`. Bold sort name lists can be obtain by patching the corresponding macros with commands from the xpatch package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,terseinits,firstinits]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% All names reversed
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

% Set sort name list in boldface
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\textbf{\newunitpunct}}%
  \xpretobibmacro{author}{\bgroup\bfseries}{}{}%
  \xapptobibmacro{author}{\egroup}{}{}%
  \xpretobibmacro{editor+others}{\bgroup\bfseries}{}{}%
  \xapptobibmacro{editor+others}{\egroup\clearname{editor}}{}{}%
  \xpretobibmacro{translator+others}{\bgroup\bfseries}{}{}%
  \xapptobibmacro{translator+others}{\egroup\clearname{translator}}{}{}}

% Omit commas in reversed names
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

% Omit "and" from \finalnamedelim except in name labels
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifcurrentname{labelname}
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
     \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
    {\addcomma\space}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
Filler text.\footfullcite{companion}
\textcite{companion,coleridge,gaonkar} show that...
\textcite{coleridge,aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric} show that...
\citeauthor{companion} show that...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your preamble:

```
% delimiter switching for cite and textcite
\let\olddelim\finalnamedelim
\let\oldtextcite\textcite

\newcommand{\switchdelim}[1]{\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{#1}}

% set up the default
\switchdelim{\addcomma\space}

% wrap the textcite command to reversibly switch the delimiter
\renewcommand{\textcite}[1]{%
{%
\renewcommand{\textbf}{}% suppress bold faced names in the running text
\switchdelim{\olddelim}%
\oldtextcite{#1}%
\switchdelim{\addcomma\space}%
}%
}

% format the author names
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{\textbf}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}{\textbf}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textbf}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}{\textbf}

% sneak a textbf into the definition of addcomma. This may be
% too much of a low-level hack, I hope there is a cleaner 
% way for doing this, but it seems to work.  
\makeatletter 
\protected\def\blx@imc@addcomma{\textbf{\blx@addpunct{comma}}}
\makeatother
```

That gives:

[image]

Comment: There are a few issues with this solution. The redefinition of `\textcite` doesn't support pre- and postnotes or citation lists. The change to `\addcomma` sets the punctuation in boldface everywhere, not just in the name list.

Comment: @Audrey - I was actually expecting that the `\addcomma` hack would affect all commas in the bibliography, but at least in this example it actually doesn't. However, I agree that your solution is preferable, since it avoids questionable hacks.

Comment: I think the comma before the year is bold. Bold commas would also appear in citations. In any case I'd rather see the commas left as-is. Given that, your solution to Q3 is preferable.